# Как прервать неудачный rebase?

Tags: linux, git, git-rebase

Ситуация: делая в командной строке интерактивный rebase из трёх правок в середине одной из них вдруг сообразил, что влил коммит не туда.

И сообразил я это в тот момент, когда на экране было что-то вроде:

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.                                                  
# The first commit's message is:                                                       

commit 1

# This is the 2nd commit message:                                                      

commit 2

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting                     
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.                    
# HEAD detached at 299f1c3                                                             
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '2ece15c'.      
#                                                                                      
# Changes to be committed:                                                             
#   (use "git reset HEAD^1 <file>..." to unstage)                                      
#                                                                                      
#       modified:   aaaaaaaaaaa.txt                  
#       modified:   bbbbbbbbbbb.txt                                    
#       new file:   ccccccccccc.txt                                 
#                                                                                      
~                                                                                      
~                                                                                      
~                                                                                      
~
```

Я увидел, что этот новый файл надо было влить в совершенно другой коммит.

И я проблему-то свою решил... Открыл новую консоль, спросил `git status` (убедился, что я нахожусь во время `rebase`) и попросил сделать `git rebase --abort`, после чего в первой консоли вышел из `vi` без сохранения (гит рунулся, что он не может применить коммит, потому что ожидает немного другой SHA ID коммита), а затем удалил временный файл от `vi` (уже не вспомню, как он назывался, кажется что-то про swap). 
Мелкими потерями времени (пришлось заново сделать первую операцию) пренебрёг. А вот если бы я делал десяток правок истории за раз и сделал бы уже пяток к моменту, когда заметил?

Поэтому сейчас вот думаю, не было ли более простого и главное -- штатного способа. Способов-то я могу придумать больше, чем тот, который использовал. Например, можно было дойти до конца `rebase`, а потом прочитав `reflog` откатиться назад к моменту до rebase. Или дойти до конца операции rebase, а затем начать новый - чтобы разбить обратно неправильно слитый коммит на два (и ещё один -- чтобы влить куда надо). В любом случае -- это мои незакоммиченные на сервер изменения, которые я как раз собирался причесать-поправить перед отправкой.

Что было бы наиболее оптимально в такой ситуации?

Comment: У меня подобные ситуации случаются, приходится скрипя зубами делать дурную работу как вы и описали, а именно: довести начатое до конца, запустить новый rebase, в котором перераспределить файлы, а потом ещё один, чтобы слить в нужное изменение.

Comment: Вы ответ так и не приняли. Он не подходит, ещё какая-нибудь информация нужна? Уточните пожалуйста, может я смогу что-то добавить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое важное в любых ситуациях: всегда иметь бэкап. Это может быть либо пуш куда-то в `origin` или на GitHub, или это может быть отдельная ветка, которая сохраняет оригинальные коммиты на случай чего:

```
git branch backup-before-rebase
```

В частности, если вы будете пробовать рекомендации из этого ответа, лучше делайте это в отдельной ветке:

```
git checkout -b stackoverflow-721125
```

Для примера, удалим какой-то один коммит:

```
$ git branch
  master
* stackoverflow-721125

$ git log --oneline -4
84bfed6 (HEAD -> stackoverflow-721125) Fifth
b5a8b20 Fourth
1824a85 Third
22d1ad4 Second

$ git rebase -i 22d1ad4
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/stackoverflow-721125.
```

Как видите, один коммит мы удалили:

```
$ git log --oneline -4
8a04495 (HEAD -> stackoverflow-721125) Fifth
1824a85 Third
22d1ad4 Second
7d005b6 First
```

Но теперь мы поняли, что ошиблись, и хотим всё вернуть как было. Самое простое будет вернуться в исходную ветку, удалить-создать временную и начать сначала.

Если бэкапа нет, или сложности не пугают, команда `git reflog` покажет какие коммиты когда-либо были верхними (то есть на них указывал `HEAD`):

```
$ git reflog -4
8a04495 (HEAD -> stackoverflow-721125) HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/stackoverflow-721125
8a04495 (HEAD -> stackoverflow-721125) HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (pick): Fifth
1824a85 HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (start): checkout 22d1ad4
84bfed6 HEAD@{3}: commit: Fifth
```

В этой выкладке `HEAD@{3}` указывает на то место, куда указывал `HEAD` три шага назад, то есть, в нашем случае, ровно до того как мы начали делать rebase. Конечно вы не будете считать шаги, а просто посмотрите на момент завершения какой команды зафиксирована запись, и остановитесь на пункте ниже.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{3}
HEAD is now at 84bfed6 Fifth
```

Как видите, мы вернули нашу ветку в то же самое состояние и в тот же самый коммит, какой был до всех операций. Ничего сложного и страшного.

---

Что если вы поняли что вы что-то делаете не так ещё в момент редактирования файла? Нет проблем! Просто напишите что-то такое, что будет непонятно Git, и выполнение прервётся с предложением вернуть всё обратно одной командой.

```
$ git rebase -i 22d1ad4
> qwe
> pick 1824a85 Third

Warning: the command isn't recognized in the following line:
 - qwe

You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'.
Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.
```

Вернёмся на исходную точку одной командой:

```
$ git rebase --abort
```

Comment: AK знает про рефлог даже, так что бэкап-ветка ему вроде как необязательна.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не у всех всё легко, потому бэкапы никогда лишними не будут. Да и быстрей может быть вернуться в свою ветку, чем читать где там какой коммит. Вот пишу дальше.

Comment: Явная копия не нужна ровно до тех пор, пока не почищены осиротевшие ветки или тэги.

Comment: @0andriy я согласен с sanmai в том, что не все знакомы с рефлогом и смогут легко им воспользоваться.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Если автор знает про рефлог, то люди, пришедшие в этот вопрос из гугла или из яндекса совершенно не обязательно знают. Свои ответы я обычно пишу не сколько для конкретно автора, сколько для всех, у кого такая же проблема. Прошу прощения за поздний комментарий.

Comment: @sanmai ну да, я ж ещё месяц назад согласился, а плюсанул и того раньше. :)