# Не работает/зависает команда git rebase

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

История такова, был у меня репозиторий на гитхабе и два коммита (учусь пока только работать с Git'ом), захотелось мне значит поменять комментарий к одному коммиту (не к последнему), так что решил попробовать комманду `git rebase -i`, знаю про всякие "последствия" использования этой команды если комитят несколько человек, то решил локально сменить название (комментарий) того саммого коммита (пердварительно удалив репозиторий на github) коммандой выше, чтобы потом залить исправленные коммиты на новы репозиторий, после ввода команды комп начал гудеть и выполнять что странное и тяжелое :) но прождав минут двадцать и не увидев после введенной команды ничего, пришлось использовать `ctl + c`, чтобы прервать это непонятное действо, затем я запустил этот код еще несколько раз но результат ожидаемо был тот же. затем я написал git `rebase --interactive` и о чудо, появился этот редактор. Первый вопрос - но это же по сути одинаковые команды или нет? почему одна сработала а другая нет? Едем дальше, открылся значит этот редактор (в сети пишут что чаще всего это vim), работаю на windows 10, вверху этого самого редактора было написано noop не знаю что это значит, но одним словом посмотрел я в этот редактор ничего не понял, как переименовать, куда нажать, как оттуда сбежать :) и решил закрыть окно, перед этим мне показали сообщение что мол есть незакрытые процессы или тип того, я нажал ок. Затем запустил Bash опять и попытался выполнить команду rebase еще раз, но теперь тот редактор не показывается и команда как будто вообще не работает, а в папке появился файл sh.exe.stackdump пару раз его удалял, но он появился опять после попытки ввести команду вновь кажется... когда ввожу команду git status, то мне пишет:

> noop   (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit) You are
>   currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on
>   'b687109'.   (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
>   (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

как я понимаю, нужно что то "доделать" но не знаю как. когда ввожу git rebase --edit-todo команда опять же выполняется вечно. подскажите что поделать и почему эти rebase-команды так туго выполняются?

Comment: попробовал еще ввести команду git commit --amend и появился vim, что то там ввел и теперь git status пишет следующее: Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

No commands done.
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   noop
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'b687109'. Может это все быть из за того, что я удалил все удаленные репозитории с github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам помогла бы простая команда `git rebase --abort`.

Если находитесь в процессе неудобного/неудачного rebase - вы всегда можете выйти из него, вернув всё в положение "как было". Мне помогало даже в [редкой ситуации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721125/213987), как раз наподобие вашей.

Команду vi не все умеют и понимают, поэтому этой пожалуй, самый популярный вопрос на stackoverflow - "[как выйти из vi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437417/213987)", набравший более миллиона просмотров на большом so.

Если не хотите изучать vi (это в общем-то просто, но не все хотят) то поменяйте на какой-нибудь другой редактор, делов-то.

Насчёт того, почему у вас так долго запускается rebase - это к шаманам. У меня ничего не тормозит, несмотря на антивирус, большом репозитории с кучей мелких файлов и даже на винтах не SSD.

Comment: делал команду, которую вы написали, тоже эффекта не было...

Comment: Да? И [где об этом информация в вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6875/213987)?

Comment: это бы что то изменило..?